# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException how can i solve this

Tags: mysql

```
try{
    stmt=conn.createStatement();


    int stdID=Integer.parseInt(id.getText());
    String stdName=name.getText();
    int stdAge=Integer.parseInt(age.getText());
    String stdAddress=address.getText();
    String stdEMail=email.getText();
    String stdDepartment=(String) department.getSelectedItem();
    String stdDesignation= (String) designation.getSelectedItem();
    int stdSalary=Integer.parseInt(salary.getText());

    String sql="INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(stdID,stdName,stdAge,stdAddress,stdEMail,stdDepartment,stdDesignation,stdSalary)"
          + " VALUES('"+stdID+"',"+stdName+"','"+stdAge+"','"+stdAddress+"','"+stdEMail+"','"+stdDepartment+"','"+stdDesignation+"','"+stdSalary+"')";

    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data is successfully inserted");


}catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

**This is my project code. I got an error while executing the code. And it shows:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException. You have an
>   error in your SQL syntex; check the  manual that corresponds  to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntex for the right syntex to
>   use near ",'21','aaaa','abc@gmail.com','A','Manager', '11111111')' at
>   line 1 **

Comment: ID
Name
Age
Address
EMail
Department
Designation
Salary

Comment: This is my database table named employee

Answer (score 0):

Your insert query has problems, such as incorrectly quoted literal values.  The best fix here is to just use a prepared statement.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (stdID, stdName, stdAge, stdAddress, stdEMail, ";
sql += "stdDepartment, stdDesignation, stdSalary) ";
sql += "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setInt(1, stdID);
ps.setString(2, stdName);
ps.setInt(3, stdAge);
ps.setString(4, stdAddress);
ps.setString(5, stdEMail);
ps.setString(6, stdDepartment);
ps.setString(7, stdDesignation);
ps.setInt(8, stdSalary);

ps.executeUpdate();
```

Prepared statements do more than protect against SQL injection.  They also free you from having to worry about how to include data in your SQL query.  You only need to know what the type of the data is, but the "how" part is handled by the statement.

Comment: oh on i thought it works. But now i am facing problem. When i insert a value it give me null in my respective database.

Comment: My guess is that the problem is with your data rather than my code.